# What does "to the 3% to 4% range" mean?

Tags: financing

It now looks almost certain that next week the Federal Reserve will raise interest rates for the third time, and that will be the first step on a clear path toward getting the price of money back to the 3% to 4% range.

Source:http://www.marketwatch.com/story/5-ways-the-fed-rate-hikes-will-hit-global-markets-2017-03-08

Comment: it means "somewhere between 3% and 4%"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It just means that they think that in the long-term, interest rates should be around 3-4%, i.e. probably between 3% and 4%, but perhaps a bit lower or higher occasionally.